# Json cpp erroring when pointed in the right place?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

When I run this code, it waits for 30 seconds or so and then the terminal exits with:
`[process exited with code 3221226505 (0xc0000409)]` which I do not recognise at all. I also had this typo `return Accounts[Account]["Balance"].asInt();` the fetch worked correctly returning a 0 to indicate a null value as it isn't there. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Minimum functioning code though some of these includes are not required

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
#include<list>
#include<cstring>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include"Header files/jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp"
#include"Header files/jsoncpp/include/json/json.h"
#include"Header files/jsoncpp/include/json/value.h"

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::to_string;

std::ifstream Information("Information.json");
Json::Value Accounts;
Json::Reader RAccounts;
bool success = RAccounts.parse(Information, Accounts);

int BaLook(string Account) {
    return Accounts["Accounts"][Account]["Balance"].asInt();
};

int main() {
    printf(to_string(BaLook("Alice")).c_str());
}
```

JSON:

```
  "Accounts": [
    {
      "Alice": [
        { "Balance": 1000 },
        { "XYZ":  1000}
      ]
    },

    {
      "Bob": [
        { "Balance": 2000 },
        { "XYZ": 10000 }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The error says stack buffer overrun: [https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xc0000409](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xc0000409)

Comment: How would I go about fixing this in my application or is it an error on the side of the JSONCPP library or my version of it?

Comment: @Correctmite I would move all those global variables to `main`, check that the file opened correctly, check the value of `success`,

Comment: Which global variables as Accounts is required to be declared before the function?

Comment: I have moved ```std::ifstream Information("Information.json");```, ```Json::Reader RAccounts;``` and have changed the parse to: ```if (!RAccounts.parse(Info, Accounts)) {
        wprintf(L"Parse Error");
        return 1;
    }```

Comment: and the problem remains

Comment: Use a debugger to inspect the call stack when it overflows. That should give you a clue as to the reason.

Comment: Also, your JSON structure does not match your access code. Did you mean `{"Accounts": { "Alice": { "Balance": 100, "XYZ": 1000 }, "Bob": {...}}}` instead of having arrays of objects?

Comment: The change in Json has fixed the issue thank you very much